# Use tensorflow-lite in pure java library

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow-lite

I have an Android application using a home made pure java library (the app build.gradle has a dependency to the library project). I'd like to use tensorflow-lite in my pure java library, not in the Android module (for design reasons).

My java library build.gradle looks like this :

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.12.0'
}
```

Android Studio sync with gradle files without problem, but when I edit a java file, **Android Studio cannot resolve the import statement** :

```
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
```

The tensorflow-lite library therefore does not appear to be imported/available, thus I can't use it.

- Has tensorflow-lite some requirements I don't know about ?
- Could it be imported in an other way when used "outside" an Android module ?
- Should I use instead the base version of tensorflow, despite it is intended to run on an Android device ?

Note :

- I have already tried to invalidate Android Studio cache
- I have already deleted ~/.gradle/cache directory
- I have no problem with other packages (for example, com.google.code.gson is imported and usable)